# Chrome 11+ (and possibly IE) not triggering OnChange after value set

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

A while back I wrote an input mask extension for jQuery which automatically filters out any non-decimal/integer values from a input elemnt, I just discovered today that this is no longer calling the onchange events if the keyup event changes the value of the input:

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/At8Ht/37/

If you view this in Firefox, it will display "Halp!" beneath the input after it is changed,when the input is blurred/loses focus, but in Chrome it does not.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Really all I am trying to do is automatically insert commas while the user is typing a large number, for example typing in "1552" yields "1,552" after the user lets go of the "2" key. This was working fine up until Chrome 11/12 :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `blur` and a little more verbosity:

```
$("#item")
    .focus(function() {
        this.previousValue = this.value;
    })
    .keyup(function() {
        this.value = new Date().getTime(); // or whatever magic code goes here
    })
    .blur(function() {
        if (this.previousValue !== this.value) {
            this.previousValue = this.value;
            $('#console').append('halp');
        }
    });
```

[**Demo on jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/tZSsX/)

Comment: Yeah I think I'll go with something along these lines - it was something I was hoping to avoid but oh well :)

One of the nifty things about this jquery plugin I wrote is that it actually binds the the form and not to the input elements, which speeds up binding *significantly*, I may be forced to bind focus/blur (or just blur if I utilize the keyup instead of focus) directly on each element, which may have a performance cost.

Thank you all for your added brainpower :)

Answer (score 2):

Change `change` to `blur`

```
$("#item").blur(function() {
    $('#console').append('halp');
});
```

---

UPDATE:

```
$("#item").blur(function() {
    $('#console').append('halp');
    $(this).trigger('change'); //trigger change
});
```

Comment: It will call that even if there was no change.

Comment: It's a good idea, but I need to use "onchange" because thats what the "TextChanged" event in ASP.NET generates in the markup.

Comment: Yeah, that would probably work, but it's not ideal.. as Niklas pointed out, that would trigger the onchange event whether or not there is a change. Considering this plugin is used throughout the application (and it's a fairly large one), this could be detrimental to performance, and cause confusion if, for example, the validation got kicked off because you tabbed over a field without filling it in.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: How about this this then?  (I'm finding it hard to understand what you're trying to simulate when setting value = 'NOPE!' though)

```
$("#item").focus(function() { this.oldValue = this.value; })

$("#item").keyup(function() {
    $(this).get(0).value = 'NOPE!';
}).blur(function() {
    if(this.value != this.oldValue){
        $('#console').append('halp');
        $(this).trigger('change'); //trigger change
    }
});
```

(OLD VERSION) Perhaps try

```
.bind('keyup', function() {
    $('#console').append('halp');
});
```

instead?

(BTW in my version of firefox it's only displaying the "halp!" when you leave the textbox, not as typing)

Comment: Thats the way it should work, it should display "halp!" once you leave the textbox (on blur), that's when onchange is typically triggered.

Unfortunately the 'keyup()' function is just a helper which calls bind('keyup', func) so that doesn't make a difference. :\

Comment: ah right. Can't you do the 'filtering' and inserting commas all in the keyup event though?  Can you share you filter?

Comment: That's what I am doing, the keyup event does all the comma insertion, and the change event should be triggered after you leave the field, but it isn't if the keyup event handler actually modifies anything in the field. 

I can't really share the code as the code belongs to another firm technically (one of our clients)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple example of this issue...
this is fixed in chrome 14... but up to 13 there is a problem...

see the example... works even in IE, but not in chrome.ver < 14

http://jsfiddle.net/nWVeX/7/

the simplest solution is to use **blur** instead of change...